# AWS Load balancer secure listener - ignore certificate in ingress-nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balance, ingress, eks, ssl

So I have an EKS cluster with `ingress-nginx`  running inside, the service of `ingress-nginx-controller` is associated with the External IP of Load balancer type `Network` (say `123.elb.my-region.amazonaws.com`).

The LB has a listener configured for port `443` and this listener has an SSL certificate in Secure listener settings. The used cert is a wildcard one matching `*.foo.bar.com`

Now I have a service in EKS which should be available under another subdomain, I've created a certificate as a k8s secret and declared its usage in ingress manifest for new service, like:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: foo
  name: new-service-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - new-service.new-foo.bar.com
      secretName: wildcard-new-foo-bar-com
  rules:
  - host: new-service.new-foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: new-service
            port: 80
```

With all this, I can still see that the certificate from LB `Secure listener settings` in AWS is served. **Is there a way to make the `ingress-nginx` ignore it and serve the one from k8s manifest -> from secret `wildcard-new-foo-bar-com`?**

I can confirm this in browser and by

```
$ curl -k new-service.new-foo.bar.com
> curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host nam
```